# Powershell parameter : string in path

Tags: string, powershell

I want to launch a .ps1 from Windows Command Prompt. My Powershell script has a path parameter. Here's my command line to launch the .ps1
`powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -scope process ; C:\\MyPowerShell.ps1 -Path \"C:\\Test for my script\test1.txt"`
In MyPowerShell.ps1, if I Write-Host Path, I get : C:\Test. It cuts my string when the first space appears.
How can I get my full path ?
Thx.

Comment: "I want to launch a .ps1 from Windows Command Prompt." Why? Open PowerShell, then run your script. You don't need the Windows command prompt (cmd.exe).

Comment: Because I'm launching it from a Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: If you can launch an executable, you don't need cmd.exe. Just run PowerShell with appropriate parameters; e.g.: `powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\MyPowerShell.ps1 -path "C:\test for my script\test1.txt"`. Run `powershell /?` for details on how to use its command line.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2:
Don't escape the path, and instead remove the quotes from what is passed in.

```
    $path2file = $path2file.replace('"',"").replace("'","")
```

This will allow anyone to put quotes around the path (an accepted practice norm) and your application strips the quotes and has the whole path in one variable.  If the path is not quoted, then this lines has no effect.

Where it will fail is if a quote (single or double) is included in the actual file path.

Answer (score 0):

I've put ' : `-Path '\"C:\\Test for my script\test1.txt"'` and it works.
Thx :)